# Setup for more "splashy" fluid 2.8

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking, effects

I'm making a simulation of object dropping into the water. In previous version of Blender it gives nice, big effect of splashing and air bubbles around an object. However, using mantaflow surface of liquid is almost untouched and bubbles are really small and rare. How can I make object interact with fluid more intensively (like on the picture below - using 2.79).[image]